# Intel mac not visibly booting

Tags: mac

I accidentally changed my screen resolution to something my monitor can't handle and I couldnÄt change it back (randomly clicking on screen which worked once before).

When I rebooted, I tried going into safe mode (held shift on the beep) and that didn't work. I tried putting in the leopard disc in hopes that I can do something about it, but even that I can't see. The only thing I can do is hold art. Press right once after a few seconds and hit enter to boot into windows.

How can I fix the screen resolution remotely? Or maybe with a linux live disc that can write to HPS+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold down Option-Command-P-R when starting your mac until you hear two beeps. This will reset the nvram and revert the screen resolution to the default setting.